# Get the first day of the current year using Moment.js

Tags: jquery, typescript, momentjs

I have two input fields to search between dates. I want the start date to default to the first day of the current year and the end date to default to today. I have the end date but I am unsure of how to get it to display the start.

```
var defaultStart =
var defaultEnd = moment((new Date()).valueOf());
$('#searchStart').val(defaultStart.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
$('#searchEnd').val(defaultEnd.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

```
var thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();    
var start = new Date("1/1/" + thisYear);
var defaultStart = moment(start.valueOf());
```

Comment: Is this answer better than [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39252190/199712)? If so, why?

Comment: The comment below utilising moment is more efficient "moment().startOf('year');"

Comment: @JasonSwett probably only because it's been answered in 2014, while the answer using moment more efficiently was posted more than two years later. Yes, I'm aware that you asked this question a year ago :)

Answer (score 171):

You could do this:

```
moment().startOf('year');
```

[format](http://momentjs.com/#format-dates) by doing something like this:

```
moment().startOf('year').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer! However, it doesn't actually work because it needs to update to be moment().startOf('year') instead of moment.startOf('year').

Comment: Be aware that `startOf` mutates an original value. If that's not required, use `.clone().startOf('year');`

Comment: The above method returns start of current year...is there a way to get the start of the year passed? like where i can pass 2017 as param and get start of 2017...

Comment: Hi, you can try doing this:  moment().startOf('year').add(-1,'years').format('MM/DD/YYYY');

Answer (score 15):

To get the start date and end date of any given year. You can pass a year as a parameter to moment.

```
startDateOfTheYear = moment([year]);
endDateOfTheYear = moment([year]).endOf('year');
```

Comment: `let fromDate=  moment().startOf('year').toDate(); `  `toDate= moment().endOf('year').toDate();` If you are using typescript with type date

Answer (score 8):

```
var defaultStart = '01/01/'+new Date().getFullYear()
```

Comment: If you don't want to use Moment.js, this answer seems best to me.